# How to split comma separated list then rejoin with added information on google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of image names in a cell in Google Spreadsheets like below:

`P262.713__B_1.jpg, P262.713__B_2.jpg, P262.713__D_100.jpg`

I need to add a URL to the start of each of these so I have:

`https://example.com/images/P262.713__B_1.jpg, https://example.com/images/P262.713__B_2.jpg, https://example.com/images/P262.713__D_100.jpg`

I am not sure how to go about this, I originally tried to do a =SPLIT() then =CONCATENATE() but this seems wrong to me and overly time consuming method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula("https://example.com/images/"&(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(, |,)","@"),"@"))))
```

where `A1` is the cell containing your text.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

Comment: Can the results be comma separated in 1 cell?

Comment: **Yes**. Use this: `=ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ","https://example.com/images/"&(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(, |,)","@"),"@"))))`. **BUT**. They will **NOT be presented as links any more**.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addUrl() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  const url='https://example.com/images/'
  rg.setValue(rg.getValue().split(',').map(function(e){return url+e;}).join(','));
}
```

To run script:

1. Select Cell
2. run function